# Evaluating Limit Using Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $f: (0,2)\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) = x^x$. Assuming the limit exists as $x$ approaches $0$, find this limit by using sequences. I know that I need to choose a sequence ($x_n$) which converges to $0$ such that $f(x_n)$ has a limit that is easy to evaluate. I tried doing it with the sequence $(x_n) = \frac1n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The problem I run into is that this sequence is not so easy to evaluate the limit with because $f(x_n)$ becomes $\frac 1n ^ \frac 1n$. This is not an easy limit to evaluate so I do not think this works so well. Is there a better choice of initial sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1/n)^{1/n}=1/(n^{1/n})$. To show that $n^{1/n}$ converges to $1$,let $n^{1/n}=1+A_n$.  We have $$n\geq 2 \implies  A_n>0,  \text { and}$$ $$n\geq 2 \implies n=(1+A_n)^n=$$$$=1+n A_n+n(n-1)A_n^2/2+...>n(n-1)A_n^2/2\implies$$ $$n>n(n-1)A_n^2/2\implies$$ $$\implies 1>(n-1)A_n^2/2$$$$\implies A_n<\sqrt {\frac {2}{n-1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer was extremely helpful